# How can I get rid of the knocking sound behind my wall when I turn any tap in the house on or off?

Tags: plumbing, water-hammer

When we turn any of our taps on or off it creates a set pattern of three knocks behind the main bedroom wall. We have a steel framed house. How can we eliminate this sound?

Comment: Do you have an expansion tank on your water line? Did this just start happening or has it always been so?

Comment: How do I get to the pipes

Comment: We bought the house a year ago and it was already like that. The house is 7 years old.

Answer (score 1):

the pipes are loose and you are hearing water hammer securing the pipes can fix the problem. another fix is to install a [absorber](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-Quiet-Pipes-1-2-in-x-1-2-in-Low-Lead-Brass-Pipe-Thread-x-Pipe-Thread-Water-Hammer-Absorber-39177/202078129?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cTHD%7cG%7c0%7cG-BASE-PLA-D26P-Plumbing%7c&gclid=CJyG9vz80ckCFQiVfgodoEQI-Q&gclsrc=aw.ds) link to one at home depot so you can see what I was referring to.